# Language is not supported during "Creating content DB" step

Tags: installation, language, farm-setup

I'm encountering a problem during the installation of sharepoint in my farm.

When it tries to create the DB the exception raised is "Language is not supported".

I think everything on the machines is set to "English (United States)" so I cannot come out from this exception..

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can be missing SP1 see [SharePoint 2010 Server SPException The language is not supported on the Server–COMException (0x8102005E)](http://blog.mjhamilton.com/?p=94)

Comment: I already had SP1 on my Windows Server 2008R2 machine..